# Почему cURL авторизация и мультизапросы не работают на локальном сервере

Tags: curl, php

Здравствуйте. Подскажите почему cURL мультизапросы не работают на локальном сервере. На хостинге всё работает. Пробывал на денвере и openserver. Ни авторизация, ни мультикурл не работает. В чем причина?

Comment: побуду кепом, возможно причина в локальном сервере ?

Comment: ну это понятно, а в чем именно?

Comment: Возможно потому что нет библиотеки php_curl.dll?

Comment: строчка раскомментированна и в папке ext есть файл php_curl.dll

Comment: Предлагаю @Хэшкод добавить простой обработчик. Если в тексте вопроса появились слова «не работает», то выводить предупреждение в духе «Обязательно опишите в чем заключается «не работает» — что Вы делаете, что Вы хотели получить, и что именно Вы получаете вместо этого.»

Иначе все это регулярно сводится к гаданию на кофейной гуще, а здесь, вроде бы, не bitva-ekstrasensov.ru.

Comment: @drdaeman, жаль не могу второй плюсик поставить ))

Comment: Не работает самым подлым образом, не выдает ошибки. Я же написал, на хостинге все ок. Что с локальным сервером сделать чтоб работало? Вот человек толковый ответ написал, проверить расширение, я это уже делал, забыл написать в описании. А вы тут демагогию устраиваете, как часто на форумах встречается.

Comment: Если ошибок нет — значит все работает. Если все-таки не работает — значит ошибка все-таки есть. Ошибка — в широком понятии этого термина — это не сообщение от шаблонизатора, а вообще вся ситуация. Вот и расскажите, наконец-то, в чем она заключается. То ли Вы пустую строку получаете вместо ответа, то ли у Вас скрипт вообще не запускается, то ли еще что-то — вариантов сколько угодно. Крайне желательно, с куском кода, минимальным, но достаточным для демонстрации что Вы делаете.

Comment: Всем спасибо за участие. Нужно было отменить проверку сертификатов. Почему на хостинге работает. Спасибо drdaeman.

Answer (score 1):

Возможные направления для диагностики:

1. Включить [`error_reporting`](http://ru.php.net/manual/ru/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) в `E_ALL | E_STRICT`. Попробовать, проверить вывод скрипта и логи веб-сервера на предмет сообщений об ошибках.
2. Ошибка может быть в коде. Пробежаться по коду пошагово, с отладчиком, смотря что там происходит. В коде, при этом, нужно не забывать проверять результаты возврата функций и значение [`curl_errno()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php).
3. Ошибка может быть и в libcurl. Стоит убедиться, что работает максимально тривиальный код с `curl_exec()`, выполняя запросы на одном из тех же URL, на которые делается запрос с `curl_multi_exec()`.
4. Ошибка может быть как при создании соединения, так и при обработке ответа сервера. Посмотреть сниффером (WireShark подойдет), создается ли соединение и что в нем происходит.

Answer (score 0):

1. посмотри в php.ini раскоментирована ли строчка extension=php_curl.dll
2. посмотри в папке с экстеншинами 'ext', располагается обычно в папке с php.exe, может называться немного не так, но созвучно